# Endless loop wont work

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm having difficulty realizing why is this part of code

```
for stanje in pomocna:
    for znak in abcd:
        novi = tablicaPrijelaza.get((stanje, znak))
        dohvatljiva_stanja.append(novi)
dohvatljiva_stanja = list(set(dohvatljiva_stanja))
dohvatljiva_stanja = sorted(dohvatljiva_stanja)
pomocna = dohvatljiva_stanja
```

not done `x` times with this implementation of a for that does x iterrations

Yet it seems that it does an endless loop.
One iterration is fine and does what it is supposed to, but after first iterration it goes nowhere
Traceback says it is stuck in second append.

Comment: what are pomocna and abcd?

Comment: If `abcd` and `pomocna` are large enough it may *seem* endless, or it could be that they are generators that *are* endless, or `dohvatljiva_stanja` is a reference to `pomocna` or `abcd` really.

Comment: pomocna is usualy 1-5 strings list, and abcd is usualy 2-3 strings long

Comment: One iterration is fine and does what it is supposed to, but after first iterration it goes nowhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper implementation is something more like this which works:

```
 for stanje in dohvatljiva_stanja:
    for znak in abcd:
        novi=tablicaPrijelaza.get((stanje,znak))
        if novi:
            pomocna.append(novi)
dohvatljiva_stanja.extend(pomocna)
dohvatljiva_stanja=list(set(dohvatljiva_stanja))
dohvatljiva_stanja=sorted(dohvatljiva_stanja)
del pomocna[0:len(pomocna)]
```